# DESPERATE Request - jQuery tag suggestion, How is it inserting the DOM Element SPAN?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

Take a look at this snazy plugin: 
http://remysharp.com/2007/12/28/jquery-tag-suggestion/
** it's real small
Source: http://remysharp.com/downloads/tag.js

For the life of me, I can't figure out where in the plugin JS the code is injecting the SPAN which contains the tags...

I see the following around line 73:

```
var tagMatches = document.createElement(settings.tagContainer);
```

But where is it injecting it into the doc? I ask because I need to find a way to control where it goes based on an ID, something like this:

```
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
```

Thanks so much, and good luck, It's tricky!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's inserted here:

```
tagsElm.after(tagMatches).keypress(handleKeys).keyup(handleKeys).blur(function () {
  if (fromTab == true || suggestionsShow) { // tweak to support tab selection for Opera & IE
    fromTab = false;
    tagsElm.focus();
  }
});
```

Specifically the [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) call.

Comment: Above this, there is:             var tagsElm = $(this);
I updated that to:             var tagsElm = $('.helper'); which ended up breaking it, no error, it just stops working. Is this inline with what you were suggesting?